# How to print to PDF using REAL PRINTER drivers?

Tags: pdf, printing, driver

Is it possible to test printer driver correct working without having a printer physically? I suppose this is it not possible because each printer uses its own print commands and protocol, so in most cases driver's output will not be recognized by 3d-party tools. But who knows...

You can find below root of the issue and what I tried to do.

A client complains that our PDF file is not printing correctly with their **HP_LaserJet_Enterprise_M506-PCL_6_Win8_Plus_Full_Soln_18141.exe   8.00.1329.4861** drivers. For testing purposes the client tried to use **HP Universal Print Driver for Windows PCL6 (64-bit) 6.8.0.24296** and and was able to print with no issues. But unfortunately they are using programs that require specific model drivers.

So, I tried to install printer drivers (different printers, actually) and map them to corresponding virtual ports for the following:

- [PDFCreator](https://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)
- [CutePDF Writer](https://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp)
- [doPDF](https://www.dopdf.com/download.html)
- OneNote
- Print to file

Unfortunately, nothing helps. PDFCreator returns "Internal Ghostscript error. (29100)"; cutePDF produces empty PDF; doPDF do nothing; OneNote generates unspecific error; print to file generates .prn which is useless without the specific printer.

So, I'm pretty sure that there is no way to verify that the drivers produces correct output stream without having physical printer corresponding to this driver. But I will be glad to be mistaken.

Comment: HP printers generally consume HP-PCL (or PXL), so that's what HP printer drivers usually produce (and the clue is in the 'PCL' in the driver names you quoted). These printers often **can** consume other formats (eg PostScript, PDF, image formats, etc) but in general the drivers will produce PCL or PXL. If you try feeding PCL to a PostScript consumer, such as PDFCreator or CutePDF it will not understand what you are sending, and will produce an error. I would suggest you instead print to FILE: and then put the resulting file somewhere public so people can look at it.

Comment: However, note that what the Windows print system sends to the printer driver is dependent on what the PDF consumer sends to the Windows printing system. In any event, if your PDF file is drawn correctly on screen, or prints correctly to other printers, then I would say this is not your problem!

Comment: I think @KenS is right, if you can verify that your PDF is correct, it becomes a problem with the third party driver. If you have Acrobat Pro, you could 'pre-flight' your PDF, and it'll let you know about any potential issues it can find. For example, overprint, transparency, fonts that aren't embedded. If there are issues here, I guess you'll need to go back to your PDF component vendor for some help. If your PDF component vendor supports PDF/X-4 as an output, it might be worth given that a go as a diagnostic. This standard is designed specifically for print scenarios.

Comment: Of course, there are always customers who require you to work around bugs or shortcomings in other peoples software. :)